# Probability inequality with intersection true /

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I was asked to verify if is this is true or false.

$$P(AB)\leq P(A)P(B)$$

I tried to find a counterexample to proof is false, but every thing I try says that the intersection is less than or equal to the product.

Comment: Did you try taking $A=B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any example where $A \subseteq B$ is a good counterexample.

In fact

$$P(AB)=P(A)\geq P(A)P(B)$$

as $P(B)\leq 1$